# How can I use geth's ecRecover to verify a signed message from TREZOR?

Tags: go-ethereum, signature, verify, trezor

I cannot get this to work. I understand from [this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14794) that TREZOR adds the magic message and a hexadecimal message length (as opposed to ASCII length) of the message before signing.

Is it just not possible to manipulate the given plaintext message by pre-pending the same data prior to sending over to geth for verification?

Comment: I don't have a TREZOR, so I have no way to try. Can you share the message you're signing, the address of the signing account, the code you're using to sign it, and the resulting signed message?

Comment: From my reading of the issue you linked to, TREZOR is not adding a hexadecimal message length; it's adding a varint. For short messages, this should just be a single byte with the length of the message.

Comment: You're right, it's varint, but the issue is with... well i'm not sure who is at fault. Trezor made the decision to "fix" the ascii representation of message length and turn it in to varint, but geth is live, in the wild, the way it is, so, unless one wants to modify the geth code and run a custom build to handle trezor signed messages, it is what it is. I don't understand the unilateral decision to do this.

Comment: Here's the data out of Trezor, if you want to fool with it yourself:
message: 3fehlpNqurkHvsEGXYVvDvh5xlxRHQMe
address: 0x3278312c573f9c0ced9b3c381b428f1821de29a4
sig: 0x6b673ad119bfba39788be3ea8ada062b74c15806a5d0520e3294817a87884a776b835dd5177f64449bd2a9445fa763ef3c3530000f317e15be54fd02480385921b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you can't use geth's `web3.personal.ecRecover` function to do this, since it adds its style of prefixing automatically. But you can use any underlying implementation of ecrecover, such as the one in web3.js, as long as you add the correct prefix, TREZOR style. The following code verifies the signature with both web3.js and [ethereumjs-util](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util):

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

const web3 = new Web3(null);

const message = '3fehlpNqurkHvsEGXYVvDvh5xlxRHQMe';
const signerAddress = '0x3278312c573f9c0ced9b3c381b428f1821de29a4';
const signedMessage = '0x6b673ad119bfba39788be3ea8ada062b74c15806a5d0520e3294817a87884a776b835dd5177f64449bd2a9445fa763ef3c3530000f317e15be54fd02480385921b';

// NOTE: Proper varint encoding is necessary for larger lengths.
const prefix = '\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n' +
               String.fromCharCode(message.length);
const stringToSign = prefix + message;

const recovered = web3.eth.accounts.recover(web3.utils.keccak256(stringToSign),
    signedMessage);

if (recovered.toLowerCase() == signerAddress.toLowerCase()) {
    console.log('Address recovered successfully via web3.js.');
}

const ethUtil = require('ethereumjs-util');

const sig = ethUtil.fromRpcSig(signedMessage);

const publicKey = ethUtil.ecrecover(ethUtil.sha3(stringToSign),
    sig.v, sig.r, sig.s);

const recovered2 = ethUtil.bufferToHex(ethUtil.pubToAddress(publicKey));
if (recovered2.toLowerCase() == signerAddress.toLowerCase()) {
    console.log('Address recovered successfully via ethereumjs-util.');
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's essentially the same as my comment where I mentioned modifying the geth code to do the same. I'm not sure this will work, though. as it still has to connect to a geth or parity node to do its job, right?

Comment: This code runs as-is, offline.

Comment: wow, thanks for the guidance. I'm getting a "Provider not set or invalid" error when attempting to do this, though. Were you able to successfully make this run and trick it to not use a provider somehow?

Comment: I passed in `null`. The code I shared is the exact code I ran. I was using Node.js 9.4.0 with `web3` 1.0.0-beta.29. What line triggers that error for you?

Comment: But if this is part of other code you're using that needs a valid provider, just use one. The `web3.eth.accounts.recover` call should be purely local, so it shouldn't matter what provider you've specified.

Comment: var recovered = web3.eth.accounts.recover(web3.utils.keccak256(stringToSign), signedMessage); is the culprit.

No, I don't actually need a valid provider and would love to not be connected to a node to do this.

Comment: What's your environment? Also Node? What version? What version of Web3?

Comment: Happy to help! I also just edited my answer to include a second way to do the verification, using ethereumjs-util instead of web3.

Comment: Id be happy to see what was the problem. I run into the same invalid provider error. The ethereumjs-util way did not work (returned different address). Also, how does this way handle when I used an address from an index lets say 44'/60'/0'/0/4 for example?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think the answer above recover the expected address from Trezor's signature. I have myself the same issue and I've find the solution reading Myetherwallet's codebase.

Trezor has a particular way to hash the message (from myetherwallet):

```
function getTrezorHash(msg) {
   return ethUtil.sha3(Buffer.concat([ethUtil.toBuffer('\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n'), getTrezorLenBuf(msg.length), ethUtil.toBuffer(msg)]));
};
```

see the "getTrezorLenBuf" function

```
function getTrezorLenBuf(msgLen) {
        if (msgLen < 253) return Buffer.from([msgLen & 0xff]);else if (msgLen < 0x10000) return Buffer.from([253, msgLen & 0xff, msgLen >> 8 & 0xFF]);else {
            return Buffer.from([254, msgLen & 0xFF, msgLen >> 8 & 0xFF, msgLen >> 16 & 0xFF, msgLen >> 24 & 0xFF]);
        }
    };
```

A working exemple validate Trezor will look like :

```
import { publicToAddress, toBuffer, fromRpcSig, ecrecover, sha3 } from 'ethereumjs-util';
import { TrezorConnect } from './trezor-connect';

(async (msg, n = 0) => {
const { address, signature } = await new Promise((resolve) => TrezorConnect.ethereumSignMessage(
  `m/44'/60'/0'/0/${n}`,
  msg,
  resolve
));

const messageHash = getTrezorHash(msg);
const { r, s, v } = fromRpcSig(`0x${signature}`);
const publicKey = ecrecover(messageHash, v, r, s);
const signer = publicToAddress(publicKey).toString('hex')

console.log(signer === address); //true
})('Hello world');
```